# Как добавить новую строку в DataGridView?

Tags: c#, access, datagridview

Код сохраняет изменения уже существующих строк, но новые не добавляет.
Как исправить сей недочет?
(Сама таблица вызывается через load форму)

```
    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView3.Rows.Count-1; i++)
         {


             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells["Surname"].Value.ToString());
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells["FirstName"].Value.ToString());
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FatherName", dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells["FatherName"].Value.ToString());
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodeEmployee", dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
             cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Storekeeper (CodeEmployee, Surname, FirstName, FatherName) VALUES (@CodeEmployee, @Surname, @FirstName, @FatherName)";
             cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Storekeeper SET Surname=@Surname, FirstName=@FirstName,  FatherName=@FatherName WHERE CodeEmployee=@CodeEmployee";

              cmd.Connection = conn;
              conn.Open();
              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

              cmd.Parameters.Clear();
              conn.Close();
          }



          System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("An Item has been successfully added", "Caption", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
          conn.Close();


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что Ваш код выполняет только `UPDATE`:

```
// Сначала Вы CommandText присваиваете инструкцию INSERT
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Storekeeper (CodeEmployee, Surname, FirstName, FatherName) VALUES (@CodeEmployee, @Surname, @FirstName, @FatherName)";
// А здесь уже в CommandText находится инструкция UPDATE
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Storekeeper SET Surname=@Surname, FirstName=@FirstName,  FatherName=@FatherName WHERE CodeEmployee=@CodeEmployee";
```

Соберите все в одно:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Storekeeper (CodeEmployee, Surname, FirstName, FatherName) 
                   VALUES (@CodeEmployee, @Surname, @FirstName, @FatherName); 
                   UPDATE Storekeeper SET Surname=@Surname, FirstName=@FirstName,  FatherName=@FatherName 
                   WHERE CodeEmployee=@CodeEmployee";
```